# How can I slice certain numbers from a file to put them as a value in a list within a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, slice, key-value

if my file is

Jessie , 90, 90, 90, 90 
   Oliver Newsome, 43, 98, 100, 56 
   Mark, 43, 78, 88, 98

I want it to show : {'Jessie': [90,90,90,90]}

What I'm having trouble with is seeing where I could slice the characters appropriatley so that despite different spacings in the file, the percentages can be put together in a slice.

Here, is what I have written for the slicing:

```
    grades = {}
    for line in filename:
        name, percentage = line.split(",")
        name_end  = line.index(',')
        name = line[0:name_end]
        percentage = [name_end:]
        if percentage not in grades:
            grades[name] = []
        [name].append(percentage)
```

Appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 0):

Going a slightly different route, you could do

```
for line in filename:
    line = line.split(',')
    line = [x.strip() for x in line]

    name = line[0]
    percentages = [int(x) for x in line[1:]]
```

Then you have name as a string with no leading/trailing spaces and an integer array percentages that you can do whatever you want with.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your file is, so I couldn't put in a reading function:

```
import numpy as np

your_data = np.asarray([["Jessie", 90, 90, 90, 90],
    ["Oliver Newsome", 43, 98, 100, 56],
    ["Mark", 43, 78, 88, 98]])

num_rows, num_columns = np.shape(your_data)
dictionary = {}
def func(data):
    x = 0
    grade_of_peoples = []

    while x != num_rows:
        grade_of_peoples = data[x,0:].tolist()
        person = grade_of_peoples.pop(0)
        dictionary.update({person:grade_of_peoples})
        x += 1
func(your_data)
```

You don't have to use numpy (I'm sure there are other ways to do it), but I personally, am biased towards it

Answer (score 0):

> Use Dict Comprehension to nail this issue, you can use re for capture names and number from strings

```
import re
_dict = {re.findall('[A-Za-z]+',i).pop():re.findall('\d+',i) for i in list(open('new.txt'))}
print(_dict)
#{'Jessie': ['90', '90', '90', '90'], 'Newsome': ['43', '98', '100', '56'], 'Mark': ['43', '78', '88', '98']}
```